# Is there a reliable discovery method, using Angular2+ or JavaScript, to find the application's environment?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angular, browser

Building a core application in Angular2+ which is being used both as a browser application and within NativeScript compiles for both iOS and Android apps. Is there a reliable discovery method, using Angular2+ or JavaScript, to find the application's environment? I'd like to use the environment variable to conditionally assign service and API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me in modern browsers and iOS but I've yet to test in Android.

```
getEnvironment(){
  let environment;
  try {
      window.document
      environment = 'browser';
      return environment;
  }
  catch(err) {
      environment = 'mobile';
      return environment;
  }
```

}